# C Program - File-io user input

Tags: c, file-io, user-input

I am trying to get a user to enter a specific file name and have the program be able to read it.

```
FILE *fp;

char file[10];

fgets(file, sizeof(file), stdin);
fp = fopen(file, "r");

if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("File doesn't open\n");
    return 1;
}
```

This is a section of my code and what i'm currently trying to do. When i run the program and enter the file name, the output is "File doesn't open" which is my error message.

Comment: You should  `fprintf(stderr, "File %s did not open: %s\n", file, strerror(errno));` in case of error

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) also incorporates the newline character `'\n'` in the string read. You need to remove it,

```
char* p;
if(p = *strchr( file, '\n' ))
    *p = '\0';
```

otherwise `fopen` will fail.

Comment: `strchr` returns `NULL` if the character isn’t found; you should probably check for that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant `fopen(file,...)`, before you can do that you must strip file of a newline.  See man pages for `fgets` and [I suggest] `strchr`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `perror` to print system error diagnostics:

```
int main(){
  FILE *fp;
  char file[10];

  fgets(file, sizeof(file), stdin);
  fp = fopen(file, "r");

  if (!fp) {
    perror(file);
    return 1;
  }
}
```

If you ask for file `f`, it'll print:

```
f
: No such file or directory
```

which should point you at the source of the problem (the `fopen` call may also fail for permissions reasons, for example).